# How to animate UITableViewCells just like apple Mail App

Tags: swift, uitableview, animation

I hope yall doing fine!.
Well I've got an edit UIButton at the top right, now when im pressing it it becomes to the usual edit style. now when it becomes edit-mode it just moves my cell fast, i would like to do an animation to it to just move it right smoothly just like the mail app: ( a gif which shows Apple Mail App)

https://media2.giphy.com/media/4u8oHz6ymC7CyjJJCZ/giphy.gif

more of it, I know there's a method of willdisply but the thing is im using IBAction for the edit button :) hope yall understand my point, happy new year.

MY CODE!:

```
import UIKit

class NotificationsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var toolBar: UIToolbar!
    
    
    
    
    
    var arrayOfNotifications = [Notification]()
    
    var selectedCounter = 0
    
    
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        arrayOfNotifications = createArrayOfNotifications()
        
        configureTableView()

        
        self.navigationItem.titleView = setTitle(title: "Notifications", subtitle: "1 New")
        
        //We hide the toolBar till we hit the "Edit"
        toolBar.isHidden = true
        
        
        configureUIButtons()
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    func configureTableView() {
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.rowHeight = 80
    }
    
    
    func createArrayOfNotifications() -> [Notification] {
        // Create Date
        let date = Date()
        
        // Create Date Formatter
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        
        // Set Date/Time Style
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
        
        // Convert Date to String
        let currentDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date) // September 9, 2020 at 12:24 PM
        
        var tempNotificationsArr : [Notification] = []
        
        let notification1 = Notification(image: UIImage(systemName: "message.fill")!, title: "Hello Aviad", date: currentDate, team: "In: Loopers")
        
        tempNotificationsArr.append(notification1)
        
        
        return tempNotificationsArr
    }
    
    
    
    
    // MARK: - UIBarButtonItem Creation and Configuration
    
     func configureUIButtons() {
        
//        let toolbarButtonItems = [
//            customTitleBarButtonItem,
//            flexibleSpaceBarButtonItem,
//            deleteBarButtonItem
//        ]
        
        let toolbarButtonItems = [
            markBarButtonItem, flexibleSpaceBarButtonItem, deleteBarButtonItem
        ]
        
        toolBar.setItems(toolbarButtonItems, animated: true)
    }
    
    
    
    var deleteBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Delete", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(NotificationsViewController.deleteButtonItemClicked(_:)))
    
    
    
//    var deleteBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
//        let deleteBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Delete", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(NotificationsViewController.deleteButtonItemClicked(_:)));
//
//        return deleteBarButtonItem
//
//    }

    
    var flexibleSpaceBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    
    
//    var flexibleSpaceBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
//        return UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace,
//                               target: nil,
//                               action: nil)
//    }
    
    
    
    var markBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Mark", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(NotificationsViewController.markButtonItemClicked(_:)))
    
//
//    var markBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Mark", image: nil, primaryAction: nil, menu: menuItems())
//
//
    
    
//
//    var customTitleBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
//        let markMenu = UIMenu(title: "", children: [
//            UIAction(title: "Flag", image: UIImage(systemName: "flag")) { action in
//                print("Flag is pressed")
//            },
//            UIAction(title: "Mark as Unread", image: UIImage(systemName: "envelope.badge")) { action in
//                print("Mark as Unread is pressed")
//            },
//        ])
//
//        return UIBarButtonItem(title: "Mark", menu: markMenu)
//
//    }
    
    
    
    // MARK: - Actions
    @objc
    func deleteButtonItemClicked(_ barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("Delete Button is clicked \(barButtonItem).")
    }

    
    @objc
    func markButtonItemClicked(_ barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem ) -> UIMenu {
        print("Mark is pressed")


        let markMenu = UIMenu(title: "", children: [
                    UIAction(title: "Flag", image: UIImage(systemName: "flag")) { action in
                        print("Flag is pressed")
                    },
                    UIAction(title: "Mark as Unread", image: UIImage(systemName: "envelope.badge")) { action in
                        print("Mark as Unread is pressed")
                    },
                ])

                return markMenu

    }
    
    
    func menuItems() -> UIMenu {
        let markMenu = UIMenu(title: "", children: [
            UIAction(title: "Flag", image: UIImage(systemName: "flag")) { action in
                print("Flag is pressed")
            },
            UIAction(title: "Mark as Unread", image: UIImage(systemName: "envelope.badge")) { action in
                print("Mark as Unread is pressed")
            },
        ])
        
        return markMenu
    }
    
    
    
    
    //TODO: - Pop up the tool bar, - Edit function
    @IBAction func editAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        
        
        if(self.tableView.isEditing == true)
        {
            self.tableView.isEditing = false
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Edit"
            toolBar.isHidden = true
            
        }
        else
        {
            tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
            
            self.tableView.isEditing = true
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Cancel"
            toolBar.isHidden = false
            
                        
            
            
//            deleteBarButtonItem.isEnabled = true
//            customTitleBarButtonItem.isEnabled = true
            
            
            
            toolBarAnimation()
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Please show us your code for `UITableView` editing. Maybe even a bit more detail and not a link? I'm commenting this because `UITableView` comes with an editing mode and animations! Not sure how they compare to Mail.app, much less the differences. But it's a good idea to show what *you* have tried, with more detail.

Comment: @dfd Sure thing, im adding my code now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
self.tableView.isEditing = true
```

use

```
self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
```

Comment: Ye im using it in setEditing, the thing is i want the cells to go smooth as Apple did :)